# Targetting Values Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here an html code with 2 functions, i dont know the reason why did the padala_condition function is not working when i am targetting the #padala-result value. I've tried other IDs and worked well.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
      <div class="form-element">
            <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala  </span>
            <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-pera"  type="number"  required="">
          </div>
          <br>
           <div class="form-element">
                  <span>C. Total Babayaran: <span id="padala-result"></span> Magkano po ang inyong ibabayad? Ang charge ay 3% Ex. kung ang pinadala ay ₱1,000 ang charge po ay ₱30 ang total na babayaran ay ₱1,030. Dapat ang perang ibabayad ay pareho o mas mataas sa babayaran. </span>
            <input type="number" name="entry.401397408" id="bayad-padala-amount" placeholder="Input Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
          </div>
          <br>
           <button type="submit" id="padala-submit">Submit</button>
       </form>

<script>
    (function padala () {
    
    $('#padala-pera').keyup(function() {
     let val = +$(this).val();
     let total = val + Math.ceil((Math.ceil(val / 500.0) * 500) * 0.03)
     if (val<=1000){
     total = val + 30
     }
      $('#padala-result').text(`₱${Math.ceil(total)}`);
    });
    
    })();
    
    (function padala_condition () {
      $("#bayad-padala-amount").focusout(function(){ 
        if(parseInt($("#padala-pera").val()) > parseInt($("#padala-result").val()))
        {
            alert("Paki-Check po ang Ibinayad");
            $("#padala-submit").prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
            $(".error").css("display","none");
            $("#padala-submit").prop('disabled',false);        
        }
        
    });
    
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, `padala-result` is span tag so you need to use `.text()` or `.html()` to get its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `$("#padala-result").val()`. Value property is applicable to input fields. `#padala-result` is a span and you have set the `text`property of span. So you have to read the `text` property itself like `$("#padala-result").text()`. This will give you the text prefixed with `₱` symbol. So to get the real numeric value you have to substring that text like

```
var padalaResult = $("#padala-result").text();
padalaResult = padalaResult.substring(1, padalaResult.length);
```

**Working Example**

```js
(function padala() {

    $('#padala-pera').keyup(function () {
        let val = +$(this).val();
        let total = val + Math.ceil((Math.ceil(val / 500.0) * 500) * 0.03)
        if (val <= 1000) {
            total = val + 30
        }
        $('#padala-result').text(`₱${Math.ceil(total)}`);
    });

})();

(function padala_condition() {
    $("#bayad-padala-amount").focusout(function () {
        var padalaResult = $("#padala-result").text();
        padalaResult = padalaResult.substring(1, padalaResult.length);
        if (parseInt($("#padala-pera").val()) > parseInt(padalaResult)) {
            alert("Paki-Check po ang Ibinayad");
            $("#padala-submit").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $(".error").css("display", "none");
            $("#padala-submit").prop('disabled', false);
        }

    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala </span>
        <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-pera" type="number" required="">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-element">
        <span>C. Total Babayaran: <span id="padala-result"></span>
        <br>
        Magkano po ang inyong ibabayad? Ang charge ay 3%
            Ex. kung ang pinadala ay ₱1,000 ang charge po ay ₱30 ang total na babayaran ay ₱1,030. Dapat ang perang
            ibabayad ay pareho o mas mataas sa babayaran. </span>
            <br>
        <input type="number" name="entry.401397408" id="bayad-padala-amount" placeholder="Input Amount" min="0"
            max="500000" step="any" required="">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="padala-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the info sir, i've test it but the alert doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Its because the condition in not satisfied. The text inside the span is always greater than the first input field.

Comment: thank you very much sir, i didnt notice the condition its working fine now :)

Comment: Okay. If your issue regarding reading the value from span is resolved, please approve my answer. Happy to have an upvote aswell.

Comment: You are welcome. Also there is no sir :). Everyone are equal and are just buddies :)